# How to configure an owned entity in order to have one to many relationship with an abstract class ef core .net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

EF Core version: 6.0.6

I have a class User which owns many class Post. The class posts own many class Comment and now I would like to handle a relationship between comments and reactions(reaction is an abstract class which can be like, star etc). As I read in the official doc I cannot implement reactions as owned because it has an inheritance hierarchy.

```
public class User
    {
        private readonly List<Post> _posts;

                public long Id{ get; }
                public string Username{ get; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; }
        public IReadOnlyCollection<Post> Posts => _posts.AsReadOnly();

                private User() : base(default, default)
        {
            CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
            UpdatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
            _posts= new List<Post>();
        }
//bla bla public constructor  etc
        }

public class Post
    {
        private readonly List<Comment> _comments;

        public long PostId { get; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; }
        public IReadOnlyCollection<Comment> Comments => _comments.AsReadOnly();

        private Post()
        {
            CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
            _comments = new List<Comment>();
        }
//bla bla public constructor  etc
    }

public class Comment
    {
        private readonly List<Reaction> _reactions;

        public long CommentId { get; }
        public string Text { get; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; }
        public IReadOnlyCollection<Reaction> Reactions => _reactions.AsReadOnly();

        private Comment()
        {
            CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
            _reactions = new List<Reaction>();
        }
        //bla bla public ctor
    }
```

and finally the class Reaction

```
public abstract partial class Reaction
    {
        public long Id { get; }

        protected Reaction() { }

        protected Reaction(long id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }
    }
```

which has two child classes
the class Star

```
public abstract partial class Reaction
    {
        public class Star : Reaction
        {
            private readonly List<Caption> _captions;

            public decimal Value { get; private set; }
            public IReadOnlyCollection<Caption> Captions => _captions.AsReadOnly();

            public Star(long id, decimal value, IReadOnlyCollection<Caption> captions) : base(id)
            {
                Value = value;
                _captions = captions.ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

and the class Like

```
public abstract partial class Reaction
    {
        public class Like : Reaction
        {
            private readonly List<Caption> _captions;

            public IReadOnlyCollection<Caption> Captions => _captions.AsReadOnly();

            public Like(long id, Caption[] captions) : base(id)
            {
                _captions = captions.ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally the class

```
public class Caption
    {
        public int Id { get; }
        public string Text { get; }

        public Caption(int id, string text)
        {
            Id = id;
            Text = text;
        }
    }
```

I have stacked how to configure the database schema.
Comments cannot own many reactions due to an owned entity cannot have an inheritance hierarchy.
I tried to implement a table-per-type solution for reactions which is abstract class.

Here is the configuration

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Users");
            builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

            builder.Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedNever().IsRequired();
            builder.Property(x => x.Username).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(x => x.CreatedAt).IsRequired();
            
            builder.OwnsMany(x => x.Posts, post =>
            {
                post.ToTable("Posts");

                post.HasKey(PostsId);

                post.Property(x => x.PostsId).ValueGeneratedNever().IsRequired();
                post.Property(x => x.CreatedAt).IsRequired();

                post.OwnsMany(x => x.Comments, comment =>
                {
                    comment.ToTable("Comments");

                    comment.HasKey(CommentId);

                    comment.Property(x => x.CommentId).ValueGeneratedNever().IsRequired();
                    comment.Property(x => x.Text).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
                    comment.Property(x => x.CreatedAt).IsRequired();

                    //how to continue the configuration of reactions and captions???
                    
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to configure a relationship between comments and reactions.A comment could have many reactions(one to many) and a reaction could have many captions(one to many)

Comment: I don't have an answer for your technical question, but I think your life would be a lot easier in creating and maintaining it, if you went with simple classes and no inheritance. For example your "Comment" could just have a list of "Stars" and a list of "Likes". The inheritance is pointless, it does not serve any purpose and your database will have to work around it anyway.

Comment: As an aside I would HIGHLY recommend not defining derived types as a subtype of the abstract. e.g. don't define child classes inside the abstract class.